# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajaxToolkit to show a modal popup. Inside the popup panel I have a repeater that has some controls from which one is a button that has an onClick  event.

In the code behind I have declared the onClick function, and inside it i register a script.

```
string str = "Are you sure?";
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Popup", "ConfirmApproval('" + str + "');", true);
```

and a javascript function in front page:

```
    function ConfirmApproval(objMsg) {
    if (confirm(objMsg)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

If i use this exact code in a new web project everything works perfectly, but if I add it in the onClick event i spoke before nothing happens. Also, all the other things in the onClick method work perfectly no matter if i add or remove the registerScript part.

Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add an OnClientClick event on your Button?
Something like:

```
OnClientClick="return ConfirmApproval('Are you sure?');"
```

should get the job done